Why is my tvOS App Icon not displaying on Apple TV despite adding it to Assets.xcassets?
I’m trying to add a tvOS App Icon to my project, but when I build and run the app on the Apple TV Simulator or device, the app icon appears blank (a white square) on the Apple TV home screen.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

I started with an existing iOS project and added a new tvOS target.
I went into the Assets.xcassets file in Xcode, clicked the + button, and selected: App Icons & Launch Images > New tvOS App Icon and Top Shelf Image.
This created a folder called Brand Assets, containing two layered image wells:

App Icon - App Store
App Icon


I added the appropriate Large and Small PNG files into the respective layers.
I built and deployed the app to the Apple TV Simulator and device, but the icon remains blank.

I also noticed that dragging images between folders in the asset catalog sometimes causes a warning about “unassigned items,” but I’m not sure if this is related.

The problem:
The issue occurs because Xcode requires you to explicitly configure the 'App Icon Set Name' in the project’s Build Settings when you add a tvOS App Icon.
The solution:

Clean up any problematic folders:

Open your Assets.xcassets catalog.
If you previously added a "Brand Assets" folder or created other folders, delete them to start fresh.


Add a New tvOS App Icon:

Ensure no folders are selected in the asset catalog.
Click the + button at the bottom and choose: App Icons & Launch Images > New tvOS App Icon and Top Shelf Image.
This will create a new folder called Brand Assets containing two layered images: "App Icon - App Store" and "App Icon".


Rename the folder (optional but recommended):

Rename the "Brand Assets" folder to something meaningful, like "tvOS Assets" (this will be referenced in the Build Settings later.)


Add your App Icon images:

Drag your Large and Small App Icon PNG files into the respective layers.
Avoid dragging images between folders, as this can break the internal references.


Update Build Settings:

Go to your project’s Build Settings tab.
Scroll down to the Asset Catalog Compiler - Options section (near the bottom).
Under Primary App Icon Set Name you'll find Debug and Release, both will be set to "App Icon" (or possibly "AppIcon").

What you want to do is add a new row underneath both Debug and Release, and set the key to Any tvOS or tvOS Simulator SDK







Build and Deploy:

Clean the project (Cmd + Shift + K) and rebuild it.
Deploy the app to the Apple TV Simulator or device.


Verify the Icon:

If the icon still doesn’t appear, try deleting the app from the Apple TV and redeploying.



